# How can the articles be divided according to the authors, and not according to the newspaper?

Tags: google-bigquery

In this code I want to divide the articles according to the author only:

```
SELECT
  NET.REG_DOMAIN(url) AS domain,
  COUNT(DISTINCT url) AS count_distinct_urls
FROM
  `project.dataset.keyword`
WHERE
  lang = 'name of author '
GROUP BY
  domain
ORDER BY
'name'
```

Comment: please share your data structure in order for your question to be actionable

Comment: `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`

Answer (score 0):

> See below (code and answer)

```
WITH
      DATA AS (
      SELECT
        "https://www.ynet.co.il/news/article/BkVraId300" AS url,
        "Naftali Bennet" AS person,
        "Hebrew" AS lang
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
        "https://www.ynet.co.il/news/article/BkVraId300",
        "Yair Lapid",
        "Hebrew"
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
        "https://www.ynetnews.com/article/FBRKZCEYJ",
        "Yair Lapid",
        "English" )
    SELECT
      lang,
      NET.REG_DOMAIN(url) AS domain,
      person,
      COUNT(DISTINCT url) AS count_distinct_urls
    FROM
      DATA
    GROUP BY
      lang,
      domain,
      person
    ORDER BY
      count_distinct_urls DESC;
```

> ```
> -- Answer:
> --    lang    domain  person  count_distinct_urls
> --    Hebrew  ynet.co.il  Naftali Bennet  1
> --    Hebrew  ynet.co.il  Yair Lapid  1
> ```